# Extension Method for Generic Class

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C# -Generic Extension Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825952/c-generic-extension-method)
>   [How do you write a C# Extension Method for a Generically Typed Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68750/how-do-you-write-a-c-extension-method-for-a-generically-typed-class)

Is it possible to declare extension methods for generic classes?

```
public class NeedsExtension<T>
{
    public NeedsExtension<T> DoSomething(T obj)
    {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825952/c-generic-extension-method

Answer (score 66):

To extend any class

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T DoSomething<T>(this T obj)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

To extend a specific generic class

```
public static NeedExtension<T> DoSomething<T>(this NeedExtension<T> obj)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: For me I forgot the <T> after the NeedExtension. More specifically I wanted to write an extention for the generic Dictionary class, so I needed <TKey,TValue>.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but you forgot the `this` keyword. Look at Queryable that provides all the LINQ operators on collections.

Answer (score 1):

Sure

```
public static void SomeMethod<T>(this NeedsExtension<T> value) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -5):

[**How do you write a C# Extension Method for a Generically Typed Cla**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68750/how-do-you-write-a-c-extension-method-for-a-generically-typed-class)ss

```
public static class NeedsExtension<T>
{
    public static string DoSomething <T>(this MyType<T> v)
    {   return ""; }

    // OR
    public static void DoSomething <T>(this MyType<T> v)
    {   
         //...
    }
}
```

Comment: this code will not compile

Comment: Extension method must be in static method, which is not able to be generic type.

Comment: Compiler error: Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Comment: This does not compile because extension methods need to be in a static non-generic class

Comment: Your class should be static.