# C# elegant way to assign properties values rather then duplication

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

i have searched for something similiar in stackoverflow and couldnt find anything which will give me some hint.

i have following code:

```
DATA val1 = new DATA();
            val1.Name = "KeyValue";
            val1.Value = "805373069";


            DATA val2 = new DATA();
            val2.Name = "Tel";
            val2.Value = "0123456789";

            DATA val3 = new DATA();
            val3.Name = "TargetID";
            val3.Value = "43301";


            DATA val4 = new DATA();
            val4.Name = "ServiceLevel";
            val4.Value = "Y";


            DATA val5 = new DATA();
            val5.Name = "TypeId";
            val5.Value = "13505";

            DATA val6 = new DATA();
            val6.Name = "DateTime";
            val6.Value = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssffftt");

            DATA val7 = new DATA();
            val7.Name = "DbDateTime";
            val7.Value = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssffftt");
```

and once all the objects are populated i put them in Single array.
i.e. to be used somewhere else

DATA[] array = {val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6,val7};

and Proxy class which i cant change is:

```
     public partial class DATA  {

private string nameField;

private string valueField;


public string Name {
    get {
        return this.nameField;
    }
    set {
        this.nameField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}

public string Value {
    get {
        return this.valueField;
    }
    set {
        this.valueField = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
    }
}
```

Now what i have tried and failed to make it easier is used Dictionary  and also jagged array and multi dimensional array which didnt worked as i hoped.

can someone give me hint of a better solution then having 7 different objects created, as this data is dynamic i have to do this runtime data population.

suggestions please?

Comment: If its runtime created doesn't this pretty much solve your problem? You create the objects in a for loop and add them to a list.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Can you explain further?

Comment: You can use object initialize. ex. new Data(){Name = "blah, Value = "blah"}

Comment: Change value from a string to an object.  Then you don't have to convert to an object and can keep value as its original type.

Comment: Also download Resharper it would have suggested this to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could initialize an anonymous object and then convert to an array of data like this:

```
var data = new {
  KeyValue="805373069",
  Tel="0123456789",
  TargetID="43301",
  ServiceLevel="Y",
  TypeId="13505",
  DateTime=System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssffftt"),
  DbDateTime=System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssffftt")
};
var array = data.GetType()
  .GetProperties()
  .Select(x=>new DATA{Name=x.Name,Value=(string)x.GetValue(data)})
  .ToArray();
```

You could also do it like this:

```
var data = new {
  KeyValue="805373069",
  Tel="0123456789",
  TargetID="43301",
  ServiceLevel="Y",
  TypeId="13505",
  DateTime=System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssffftt"),
  DbDateTime=System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssffftt")
};
var array=System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(data)
  .Select(x=>new DATA {Name=x.Key,Value=(string)x.Value})
  .ToArray();
```

If you need to take an array of data and convert it back into a class object (not anonymous), you can do the first method, just in reverse as well.  Or put extension methods on it to convert from/to your data array.

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static DATA[] ToDataArray(this object data)
    {
        return data.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Select(x=>new DATA{Name=x.Name,Value=(string)x.GetValue(data)})
            .ToArray();
    }
}
var data = new {
  KeyValue="805373069",
  Tel="0123456789",
  TargetID="43301",
  ServiceLevel="Y",
  TypeId="13505",
  DateTime=System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssffftt"),
  DbDateTime=System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmssffftt")
};
var array=data.ToDataArray();
```

However, David's answer is better.

Comment: this worked very well for me as you have given extensive examples and first and last code part was great.

Answer (score 3):

Put all data in a dictionary if you want to make sure names must not be duplicated:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, string>();

// fill dictionary:
data.Add("name1", /*value*/);
data.Add("name2", /*value*/);
data.Add("name3", /*value*/);
data.Add("name4", /*value*/);
```

Then convert it to array:

```
return data.Select(d => new Data(){ Name = d.Key, Value = d.Value}).ToArray();
```

Make sure you have included `using System.Linq` in top.

**UPDATE**:
As @LukeH suggested, You can simply use [collection initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) like this:

```
var data = new Data[]
{
    new Data(){ Name = "Sylvester", Value = /*value*/ },
    new Data(){ Name = "Whiskers", Value = /*value*/ },
    new Data(){ Name = "Sasha", Value = /*value*/ }
};
```

Which doesn't prevent duplicate names for `Data` type instances.

Comment: You could also reduce superfluous code by using collection initializer syntax to populate the dictionary.

Comment: Depending on the use-case, this has the benefit/detriment of enforcing unique Name values for the Data array result.  This is good if the Data objects are used within some functionality where duplicate names may cause unexpected behavior, as it will create a meaningful exception before then.  This is bad if Data is used just for some information/reporting purposes, where duplicate names are allowable (or even common).

Answer (score 3):

You could just declare the objects in-line as part of the array declaration, if all you're trying to do is avoid having the variables:

```
DATA[] array = {
    new DATA { Name = "something", Value = "something else" },
    new DATA { Name = "something", Value = "something else" },
    new DATA { Name = "something", Value = "something else" },
    new DATA { Name = "something", Value = "something else" }
};
```

Anywhere that you have a variable, you can instead have the operation which created that variable.  The order of operations will result in evaluating to the same thing.  Where you'd need a variable is where you want to use the same *instance* of something multiple times, or the same value without having to re-calculate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb383977.aspx) something like this to overcome the problem of assign properties values rather then duplication,

```
 static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddDataObject(this List<DATA> dataList, params string[] values)
    {
        dataList.Add(new DATA() { Name = values[0], Value = values[1] });
    }
}
```

and passing that values as per given below,

```
 List<DATA> dataList = new List<DATA>();
 dataList.AddDataObject("KeyValue", "805373069");
 dataList.AddDataObject("Tel", "0123456789");
```

Here in above example I used List instead of array, you can change according to your requirements

Comment: i would love to use this method but problem is extension method must be defined in non-generic static class and my worker class is generic class with internal methods.

Comment: Here is [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292597/extension-method-for-generic-class) for how to add extension method in generic class